# Jquery UI Autocomplete - Selected result to DIV rather than form field

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, html, autocomplete

I wonder if somebody would be kind enough to help me with my query?

I have the following code that works great, however I would like to post one of the selected results to a DIV rather than a form field.

I've tried 101 things myself but the solution is beyond me.

I also thought that making the form field hidden and copying the contents into the DIV with Javascript would be a solution until I realized that I did not know how to do that either...

```
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: 'complete_client.php',
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#id" ).val( ui.item.id );
            $( "#title" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $( "#spec" ).val( ui.item.spec );
            document.forms["main_search"].submit();
    }
    });
```

I would, where possible like the id to remain in the form field with the title and the spec to populate a DIV.

Should it not be possible/too much work, would automatically copying the form contents into a DIV be possible/easier with Javascript?

Many thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: 'complete_client.php',
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // Put selected item's text into div
        $('#divid').text(ui.item.value);

        /* Whatever other code you want here */
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew but I tried that and it didn't and doesn't work for me.  Initially I hoped it was going to be that simple too - any further suggestions?  Thanks  Chris

Comment: Aplogies Matthew, your answer was perfectly correct - an error else where in my code was stopping your suggestion working.  Again thanks